# Aggregating isochrones with accessibility values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, isochrone, aggregate

I have created a series of isochrones for public transport, for the bus, tram and train, with a 5 and 10 minute walking range. Now I would like to aggregate these values to show which areas are most accessible.

[image]

I have assigned 1-6 values for each of these layers, which I would then like to aggregate, for instance, 5 minutes access to a train station has the value of 6, but when it would be accessible by tram within 5 minutes, the shape should get an even higher value. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Please tell us a little bit more about your data: you have raster or vector data you want to aggregate? How is it structured? Best would be sharing your project/data (at least a sample) for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raster layers, use raster calculator and create the sum of the values. For polygon layers, proceed as follows:

1. Get all your isochrone layers in one with [Merge vector layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#merge-vector-layers)
2. Get the [Bondary](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#boundary)
3. Create separate polygons with [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?#split-with-lines) (inputs: layeres from step 1 and 2)
4. [Delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#delete-duplicate-geometries)
5. Use this expression to calculate for each intersecting part the sum of the `value` attribute from all the layers that are mentioned in line 3 ([`array_sum`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#array-sum) is available [since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays)):

```
array_sum (
    array_foreach (
        array ('poly1','poly2','poly3'),
        array_sum(
            overlay_within( @element, value)
)))
```

*The expression is used here as dynamic label to calculate the sum of the intersection polygons. Red polygon has `value` 1, yellow of 2 and blue of 3. The black lines shows the splitted polygons (intersecting parts):*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I eventually came up with a different solution:
I first dissolved the isochrones to create polygons for each mode of transport and travel range. Then I intersected the ones that were relevant, merged the layers and added a new numeric field with 1-14 values, to sort and weight their importance.